# How do I keep style `a span` from jumping down to the next line?

Tags: html, css

This fluid design works fine on all browsers on my laptop, but on my android and iphone the link button is split between two lines. If I change the width percentage of style (a span) I can get it to work, but then it's width is no longer as wide as the container below it and it's needs to be.

I was assuming that style (a span) could only fill in the area between style (a em) and style (a b), I guess I was wrong.

Thanks in advance for anyone that can help me on this.

Styles

```
.main_container {

    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../images/bgdots.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x y;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

h2.acc_trigger {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 2px 0;
    width: 95%;
    height: 30px; 
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;   
    margin-right: auto;   
}

a em{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/navs.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 26px;
    height: 30px;
} 


a span{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/navs_c.png) repeat-x;
    width: 95%;
    height: 30px;
}

a b{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/navs.png) no-repeat -28px 0;
    width: 5px;
    height: 30px;
} 

.acc_container {
    margin: 0 0 2px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 95%;
    clear: both;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #3cf;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px; 
    margin-left: auto;   
    margin-right: auto;   
}
```

Example HTML

```
      <h2 class="acc_trigger">
        <a href="#"><em>&nbsp;</em> <span>
        home</span> <b>&nbsp;</b></a>
      </h2>

      <div class="acc_container">
        <h3>
          Content content content!
        </h3>
        <p>
          Content and more content, content with style and interest
          that makes you want to read on. 
        </p>
      </div>
```

Comment: Not really related, but I would recommend using `{font-style:italic}` rather than `<em>`.

Comment: you can change the display: block to display:inline

Answer (score 0):

add in style `float:left` might resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

You want your  to have a percentage as well. I assume you want the code to work like my [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/25VZB/2/)

```
a em{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/navs.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 2%;
    height: 30px;
} 

a b{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/navs.png) no-repeat -28px 0;
    width: 2%;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Basically 95% plus 26px plus 26px can equal > the screen. So it wraps. You want all three of those elements to have a percentage to keep it jiving.

Comment: @ACarter, I agree about not using `<em>` as it isn't really kosher anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need inline styles if you are using CSS

```
 <h2 class="acc_trigger">
 <a href="#"><em>&nbsp;</em> <span> home</span> <b>&nbsp;</b></a>
  </h2>
```

should be

```
<h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="#">home</a></h2>

a.acc_trigger{
 font-style:italic;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

H2 is a block-level element.  If you want to make it inline just do this:

```
<h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="#">home</a></h2>

a.acc_trigger{
 font-style:italic;
 font-weight: bold;
 display: inline;
}
```